# reactjs material-ui how to style auto complete which always cover the text field

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a little problem with auto complete.

I have a lot of data returned by my API and when I type a word in the autocomplete search bar, the dropdown hide the text input.

I tried to override the style:

```
<AutoComplete
    hintText="For example, Coca-Cola"
    floatingLabelText="Search entities"
    onUpdateInput={this.updateInput}
    dataSource={autoCompleteDataSource}
    filter={this.caseInsensitiveFilter}
    menuStyle={styles}
    ref="searchBox" />


 var styles = {
   top: '53%'
 };
```

but this doesn't work at all (maybe am I trying to override it in a wrong way?).

Does anyone has an idea about it?

Many thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by *a lot of data* - 100, 1000?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. In which way could it help to know that?

Comment: because I couldn't reproduce it (tried with 100 options). what material-ui version are u using?

Comment: Oh ok, I am using the `0.14.2` version!
I think I am also having ~100 options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use anchorOrigin, which is the location of the anchor for the auto complete. It has a default value { vertical: 'bottom', horizontal: 'left' }.